# Which GPO-applied security settings are tattooed on the system and how to identify them?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I need to remove a couple of old Group Policies that applied security settings to our servers.
(*Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment*).

I always thought they were tattooed on the system, like the ones in *Audit Policy* or *Security Options*,  but noticed out that this is not so. My test server did in fact revert to a previous setting or default setting.

Upon investigating this, I found a documentation on that.

> ## Persistence of security settings policy
>
> Security settings can persist even if a setting is no longer defined in the policy that originally applied it.
>
> Security settings might persist in the following cases:
>
> - The setting has not been previously defined for the device.
> - The setting is for a registry security object.
> - The settings are for a file system security object.
>
> All settings applied through local policy or through a Group Policy Object are stored in a local database on your computer. Whenever a security setting is modified, the computer saves the security setting value to the local database, which retains a history of all the settings that have been applied to the computer. **If a policy first defines a security setting and then no longer defines that setting, then the setting takes on the previous value in the database. If a previous value does not exist in the database then the setting does not revert to anything and remains defined as is. This behavior is sometimes referred to as "tattooing".**
>
> Registry and file security settings will maintain the values applied through Group Policy until that setting is set to other values.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/security-policy-settings

Now, before I clean up those GPOs, I need to know

1. which systems have been tatooed by the obsolete policy settings, so I can manually revert the settings,
2. and what was the value that the security setting is going to revert to, when I remove the GPO.

How can I do that?